Rules to draw Lewis dot structures
This long video on how to draw Lewis dot structure elaborates on some weird rules that I have never encountered. Can anyone quote a reference to these rules, and what their limitations are?
It says the following rules:

For choosing the central atom the priority order: least in number/ electronegativity least/size largest/ At No. highest.

H and F can't be central atoms.

Covalency is the number of bonds + number of lone pair electrons

Valencies of some atoms:
O Normal:2 Possible: 1,2 ,
S Normal:6 Possible: 2,4,6
N Normal:4 Possible: 3,4
P Normal:5 Possible: 3,5
C Normal:4 Possible: 4
Si Normal:4 Possible: 4
Cl Normal:7 Possible: 1,3,5,7

Positive charge on a cation will always be present on the central atom, and negative charge on anion on the corner atoms.

Central atom always has 8 or more electrons.

Central atom always tries to attain the highest covalency if electrons are available to it.


Steps to draw lewis structures:

Calculate the total no of valence electrons of all atoms.

Make a single bond between the central atom and the corner atoms. The number of electrons used in this are called bond pair electrons.

Subtract electrons used in making bonds and assign the remaining as lone pairs to corner atoms completing their octet.

If covalencies of central atom or corner atom are not satisfied convert the lone pairs electrons into a bond making double or triple bonds.

In-case covalencies are still not satisfied calculate the formal charge on each atom and assign that charge to the atom.

In case 2 Lewis structures are possible the one with neutral atoms is more stable than the one with charged atoms. Also one in which central atom has the highest covalency is more stable. These structures will produce a resonance hybrid having characteristics more of the one which is more stable.



Are lewis dot structures prevalent anymore? 3) Covalency doesn't include lone pairs 6) How would you explain incomplete octets as in BF3

Lewis structures, useful as they are, do not deserve this much thinking.

I guess that is one of the limitations of the Lewis Theory @CuckooBeats

@ojasdessai I am not well acquainted with the Lewis bond theory literature, you could however study it from NCERT Chemistry class-11 chapter-4 : Chemical Bonding


Who other than some poor school kids Lewis dot structures? 2) Your rules aren't for drawing them, they're for finding structural formula from molecular one. This is a wrong approach. You should learn it gradually by seeing a lot of structures.


Rule 2 fails in some cases - bifluorite ion, trihydrogen cation. There are also so many exceptions to these rules.
